# How do I add a date last accessed field to a record in MS Access 07

Tags: microsoft-access

It wants to come up automatically and be logged with all the previous dates and be uneditable to the base user.

What should I do?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Do you mean a field to flag the last time a record was read, updated, inserted? Are you using a front end form for modifying the data or the table view directly?

Answer (score 0):

Before Access 2010, the only way was to use events in forms to stamp the record with date/time in a field devoted to that purpose.

A2010 implements table-level data macros that allow you to implement the equivalent of a trigger to do this without using form events. I don't know how to do it, but it's now possible.